# Angularjs: ng-model setting value from controller

Tags: angularjs

how to set value of ng-model with dot from controller?

```
<input type=text" ng-model="user.latitude">
```

this doesn't work:

```
$scope.user.latitude = myLat;
```

Comment: use $scope.user = {latitude: myLat}; in your controller

Answer (score 4):

You need to create `user` object first:

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.latitude = myLat;
```

or shorter:

```
$scope.user = {latitude: myLat};
```

Comment: yes, but this will clear other values of user, for example 'ng-model="user.name"', how to edit only 'user.latitude'?

Answer (score 0):

I have users_review as array of objects and just to replace specific key of array element, I have modified my code as,

```
$scope.users_review[index].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only possible way of doing this. You have to make an object first then only you can enter something into it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name.fname"><br>



</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name={};
   $scope.name.fname="test";
   
   //$scope.name={fname:"test"};
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```